# Proof of Expectation of a Function of a Random Variable

Tags: probability, expectation

$$ E(aX + b) = aE(X) + b $$

$$ E(aX + b) = \sum_x(ax+b)p_X(x) = a\sum_xp_X(x) + \sum_xbp_X(x)  = aE(X) + b$$

Could someone extrapolate on this proof a little, I'm a little confused why the constant b is included in a sum given it's not multiplied by the rv X. Or is that purely a formalism when dealing with an expectation.

Comment: It's perfectly legitimate to consider a random variable with a constant added as a random variable in its own right. Perhaps at a certain post office, packages cost $\$3W+2$ to mail, when the package weighs $W$ pounds. Then if the weight is random, the cost is a random variable, and one might want to compute the expected value of the cost- but the formula above says that you essentially have no work to do if you know $E(W).$

Comment: It is a special case of $E[f(X)] = \sum_x f(x) p_X(x)$. But you are right, in the end it does not really matter (which is what the proof you have written is showing).

Comment: Looks okay, save for the typo-dropped $x$ in the second last step. Also if you are going to distribute constants out of the series, you may as well treat both the same.  $$\ldots ~=~a\sum_x x\,p_X(x) +b\sum_x p_X(x)~=~\ldots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking it one step at a time.

$$\begin{align} \mathsf E(aX + b) &= \sum_x(ax+b)p_X(x) &&{\text{definition of expectation}\\  \text{/ law of unconscious statistician}} 
\\[1ex] & = \sum_x \big(ax\,p_X(x) + b\,p_X(x)\big) && \text{distribution} 
\\[1ex] & = \sum_x ax\,p_X(x) ~+~ \sum_x b\,p_X(x) && \text{association}
\\[1ex] & = a\sum_x x\,p_X(x)~+~ b\sum_x p_X(x) && \text{distribution} 
\\[1ex] & = a\sum_x x\,p_X(x)~+~ b && \text{law of total probability} 
\\[1ex] &  = a\,\mathsf E(X) + b && \text{definition of expectation}
\\[2ex]\therefore\quad\mathsf E(aX+b) ~&=~ a~\mathsf E(X)+b && \text{quad erat demonstrandum }
\end{align}$$

$\blacksquare$

> I'm a little confused why the constant b is included in a sum given it's not multiplied by the rv X.

The step is just associating the series into two so that you can treat the terms separately.   Then by distributing the constants out you can see that $b$ is multiplied by the total probability; demonstrating that $\mathsf E(b) = b$.   That was a step your proof skimmed over; likely feeling that it was obvious.